# Rails Incomplete response received from application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

`Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64)`
`ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]`
`Rails 2.3.14`
`Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`
`Phusion Passenger version 5.0.21`

```
App 6748 stderr: Error during failsafe response: "\xD0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
App 6748 stderr: 
[ 2015-11-20 12:58:26.6770 6711/7f2455b2f700 age/Cor/Req/Utils.cpp:96 ]: [Client 1-19] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
App 6748 stderr: [ 2015-11-20 12:58:26.6772 7800/0x000000020fcf88(Worker 1) utils.rb:87 ]: *** Exception NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
App 6748 stderr: You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
App 6748 stderr: The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]) (process 7800, thread 0x000000020fcf88(Worker 1)):
App 6748 stderr:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:127:in `process_request'
App 6748 stderr:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 6748 stderr:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
App 6748 stderr:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
App 6748 stderr:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
[ 2015-11-20 12:58:31.0215 6711/7f245c2fd700 age/Cor/App/Poo/AnalyticsCollection.cpp:105 ]: Process (pid=7800, group=[application_folder] (development)) no longer exists! Detaching it from
the pool.
[ 2015-11-20 12:58:31.0215 6711/7f245c2fd700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:794 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 7800, application [application_folder] (development)
App 7852 stdout:
```

I tried converting all controller source files to UTF-8 format and adding `#encoding: utf-8` in the beginning of the file. Tried adding keys to `app/secret.yml`, restarted server, but nothing happens.

Apache log says something about `ActiveRecord::Base`. But I've only generated some models and didn't touched files in `app/models/*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cause I'm using unicode simbols in controller.
When I set encoding of all controllers in `RAILS_ROOT/app/controllers/*` to `UTF-8` not to `UTF-8 without BOM` all works fine.